# How to deploy into Heroku my Angular2 web application?

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment, build

I have a very simple Angular2 application (only the index.html) and I created an account on Heroku.
I had to add into my Heroku account the Node.js as buildpack

I followed, step by step, what is written into this link:
https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147. I fixed some known problems until the deploy is done.

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const path = require( 'path' );

const app = express();

app.use( express.static( __dirname + '/dist/demo-deploy-app2019' ) );

app.get( '/*' , function( req , res ) {
    res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname + '/src/index.html' ) );
} ); 

app.listen( process.env.PORT || 8080 );
```

When I view the page, it is completly blank.
When I inspect the page, I see exactly my index.html code, like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>DemoDeploy</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not see the 
     that I have if I run the same Angular2 application locally, running it with ng serve.

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I lost the "I do not see that I have if I run the same Angular2 application locally" is the several .js script that angular2 includes in order to work properly

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>